# Transaction not active - @OneToOne Shared Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, persistence

I'm with this problem and was thinking if you could help me solve it. It's just a simple relationship between UserLogin and UserProfile, when an UserProfile has it's primary key as a foreign key that references UserProfile's primary key.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PlataformaPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>ptf.model.entities.UserLogin</class>
    <class>ptf.model.entities.UserProfile</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/negociacao_db"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="vmribeiro"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="titogzej4"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Classes

-- UserLogin

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario_login")
public class UserLogin implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_usuario_login")
    private long idLogin;

    @Column(name = "email_usuario")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "senha_usuario")
    private String senha;

    @Column(name = "tipo_usuario")
    private int tipo;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userLogin")
    private UserProfile userProfile;

    public UserLogin() {
    }

    public long getIdLogin() {
        return idLogin;
    }

    public void setIdLogin(long idLogin) {
        this.idLogin = idLogin;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public int getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(int tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserLogin{" + "idLogin=" + idLogin + ", email=" + email + ", senha=" + senha + ", tipo=" + tipo + ", userProfile=" + userProfile + '}';
    }


}
```

--UserProfile

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuario_perfil")
public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_usuario_perfil")
    private long idProfile;

    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario_login")
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    private UserLogin userLogin;


    @Column(name = "nome_usuario")
    private String nomeUsuario;

    @Column(name = "sobrenome_usuario")
    private String sobrenomeUsuario;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "nasc_usuario")
    private Date dtNasc;

    @Lob
    @Column(length=100000, name = "avatar_usuario")
    private byte[] avatar;

    @Column(name = "cpf_usuario")
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "rg_usuario")
    private String rg;

    @Column(name = "estado_usuario")
    private String estado;

    @Column(name = "cidade_usuario")
    private String cidade;

    @Column(name = "nota_anunciante")
    private double notaAnunciante;

    @Column(name = "qtd_negociacoes_anunciante")
    private long qtdNegociacoes;

    @Column(name = "cep_usuario")
    private String cep;

    @Column(name = "cel_usuario")
    private String cel;

    public UserProfile() {
    }

    public long getIdProfile() {
        return idProfile;
    }

    public void setIdProfile(long idProfile) {
        this.idProfile = idProfile;
    }

    public UserLogin getUserLogin() {
        return userLogin;
    }

    public void setUserLogin(UserLogin userLogin) {
        this.userLogin = userLogin;
    }

    public String getNomeUsuario() {
        return nomeUsuario;
    }

    public void setNomeUsuario(String nomeUsuario) {
        this.nomeUsuario = nomeUsuario;
    }

    public String getSobrenomeUsuario() {
        return sobrenomeUsuario;
    }

    public void setSobrenomeUsuario(String sobrenomeUsuario) {
        this.sobrenomeUsuario = sobrenomeUsuario;
    }

    public Date getDtNasc() {
        return dtNasc;
    }

    public void setDtNasc(Date dtNasc) {
        this.dtNasc = dtNasc;
    }

    public byte[] getAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }

    public void setAvatar(byte[] avatar) {
        this.avatar = avatar;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getRg() {
        return rg;
    }

    public void setRg(String rg) {
        this.rg = rg;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public double getNotaAnunciante() {
        return notaAnunciante;
    }

    public void setNotaAnunciante(double notaAnunciante) {
        this.notaAnunciante = notaAnunciante;
    }

    public long getQtdNegociacoes() {
        return qtdNegociacoes;
    }

    public void setQtdNegociacoes(long qtdNegociacoes) {
        this.qtdNegociacoes = qtdNegociacoes;
    }

    public String getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(String cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    public String getCel() {
        return cel;
    }

    public void setCel(String cel) {
        this.cel = cel;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserProfile{" + "idProfile=" + idProfile + ", userLogin=" + userLogin + ", nomeUsuario=" + nomeUsuario + ", sobrenomeUsuario=" + sobrenomeUsuario + ", dtNasc=" + dtNasc + ", avatar=" + Arrays.toString(avatar) + ", cpf=" + cpf + ", rg=" + rg + ", estado=" + estado + ", cidade=" + cidade + ", notaAnunciante=" + notaAnunciante + ", qtdNegociacoes=" + qtdNegociacoes + ", cep=" + cep + ", cel=" + cel + '}';
    }

}
```

--UserDAO

```
class UserDAO implements IUserDAO {

    public EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PlataformaPU");
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean save(UserLogin ul) {
        boolean result = false;

        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            if (ul.getIdLogin() == 0) {
                //If this entity does not exist, insert
                em.persist(ul);
                result = true;
            } else {
                if (!em.contains(ul)) {
                    //If this entity has to exist but was not found in db, error
                    if (em.find(UserLogin.class, ul.getIdLogin()) == null) {
                        throw new Exception("Erro ao atualizar o login!");
                    }
                }
                //If this entity exists and can be found in db, update
                em.merge(ul);
                em.flush();
                result = true;
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            result = false;
        } finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(long id) {
        boolean result = false;
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        UserLogin ul = em.find(UserLogin.class, id);

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(ul);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            result = true;
        } finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public UserLogin findById(long id) {
        UserLogin result = null;
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        try {
            result = em.find(UserLogin.class, id);
        } finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserLogin> findAll() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        List<UserLogin> result = null;
        try {
            Query q = em.createQuery("select u from UserLogin u");
            result = q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public UserLogin findByEmail(String email, String senha) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        UserLogin result = null;
        try {
            Query q = em.createQuery("select u from UserLogin u where u.email=:email");
            q.setParameter("email", email);
            result = (UserLogin) q.getSingleResult();
        }catch (NoResultException ex){
            //I'll be defined a message on controller when it's null
            result = null;
        } 
        finally {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

-- The main class that I'm using to test.

```
public class PlataformaNegociacaoBase {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        UserProfile up = new UserProfile();
        up.setAvatar(null);
        up.setCel("12314141");
        up.setCep("12312-13");
        up.setCidade("São Paulo");
        up.setCpf("2141123");
        try {
            up.setDtNasc(df.parse("21/11/1997"));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlataformaNegociacaoBase.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        up.setEstado("SP");
        up.setNomeUsuario("Joao");
        up.setNotaAnunciante(0);
        up.setQtdNegociacoes(0);
        up.setRg("234142512");
        up.setSobrenomeUsuario("Pedro");

        UserLogin ul = new UserLogin();
        ul.setEmail("joao@joao.com");
        ul.setSenha("123");
        ul.setTipo(1);

        up.setUserLogin(ul);
        ul.setUserProfile(up);
        IUserDAO uld = DAOFactory.getUserLoginDAO();
//        ul = (UserLogin) uld.findById(3);
//        System.out.println(ul);
//        ul.setEmail("jonas@alter.com");
//        ul.setSenha("alterjonas");
        System.out.println(uld.save(ul));
//        System.out.println(uld.remove(3));
//        List<UserLogin> all = (ArrayList<UserLogin>)uld.findAll();
//        all.forEach((userLogin) -> {
//            System.out.println(userLogin);
//        });
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:105)
    at ptf.model.dao.UserDAO.save(UserDAO.java:50)
    at ptf.model.dao.UserDAO.save(UserDAO.java:15)
    at ptf.test.PlataformaNegociacaoBase.main(PlataformaNegociacaoBase.java:58)
C:\Users\Victor Ribeiro\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

> It's just a simple relationship between UserLogin and UserProfile, when an UserProfile has it's primary key as a foreign key that references UserProfile's primary key

I don't understand this, but I can give you some advises.

Firstly, to solve you task you should to use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`

Better to use

```
private Long idLogin;
```

You have complex method `save(UserLogin ul)` just throw away all this garbage and use something simply.

I think you can use `merge()` with `Long idLogin`. If you need to check existence of `idLogin` — method `save()` is not a good place for it.